# What is the correct way to add an abstract public getter and a private setter?

Tags: kotlin

I have an interface where I want a property that can be modified innside the class, but not outside. I cannot use val because it needs to be mutable and the var keyword can not have a specified private setter since this is in an interface.

In Java I would have done this:

```
public <T> getMyProperty();
```

I can use the same approach in kotlin and just write the getter function dirrectly, but this does not seem like a kotlinlike approach. Is there a better way to achieve the same as this?

```
fun getMyProperty()
```

Comment: This is unclear - you say private getter in the Q title, then show a public one as example. As a matter of fact "abstract private" makes no sense.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In Kotlin, you can actually `override` a `val` with a `var`, so, I think, what you want can be expressed as follows:

```
interface Iface {
    val foo: Foo
}
```

```
class Impl : Iface {
     override var foo: Foo
         get() = TODO()
         private set(value) { TODO() } 
}
```

Or you can override the `val` with a property with a backing field and default accessors:

```
class ImplDefaultGetter : Iface {
    override var foo: Foo = someFoo
        private set
}
```

In both cases, the mutability and the presence of a private setter become an implementation detail of the classes and are not exposed through the interface.

Comment: never knew we can do this, thanks for this!